# Non-featured posts displayed as such in the app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I have the idea that non-featured meta posts are displayed as if they are in the app feed.

Or does featured mean something else here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Those posts are featured **by the app**; e.g. the app recommended a hot Meta post for you. This isn't limited to Meta posts, although non-meta featured posts are called 'hot'. The same question is appearing in the 'community bulletin' yellow box on the Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow websites under "Hot Meta Posts".

Yes, that's a different concept from the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag on Meta sites.

Comment: What does that mean, featured by the app? Is it like 'recommended for you'?

Comment: @CamilStaps: exactly, just like the 'hot' posts.

Comment: Okay, that's confusing. Do you have some reference for that?

Comment: @CamilStaps: no, just a lot of experience using the app.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer, but I think you'll understand that I'll wait for an authoritative answer ;-)

Comment: @Camil better chance of having this tagged as [tag:status-bydesign] (or retagged as [tag:support], depending on the dev who will review it) than having extra answer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard sure. Of course, but I'll wait for the retag before accepting this answer, is what I meant