# Featured meta post is displaying twice in android app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I see some times few of the **Featured meta post**s are displaying twice in the android app feed.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Post Repeating-1] [image: Post Repeating-2]

Stack Exchange Android App Version **1.0.77**

<sub>Note: Not all the featured meta posts are displaying twice, very few of them</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because the app feed "featured meta post" is taking from two sources:

1. Questions with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.
2. Questions with high score and highly upvoted answers, aka "hot meta posts". ([Related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244119/non-featured-posts-displayed-as-such-in-the-app-feed))

This can be seen in the sidebar Community Bulletin as well:

> [image]

So when a question (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well)) answers both of the above, it might appear twice in the feed. I'm pretty sure this bug also existed in the bulletin itself, and was fixed only recently.